# regex find "less than" and insert "^" before

Tags: asp.net, regex, string, escaping

i have a simple string like "aaa<bbb>ccc". i want to insert a "^" before "less than" using regex. i want to escaping the "less than"-symbol. but what ever i do, it didnt works.

```html
str = "aaa<bbb>ccc"
str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(message, "(?<=<)", "^$&")
response.write(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a positive lookahead assertion.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(message, "(?=[><])", "^");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dH4cL3/2)

This would add `^` symbol before less than and greater than symbols.

Comment: output: aaa^ccc and not aaa^<bbb^>ccc

Comment: is this `aaa^<bbb>ccc` your expected output?

Comment: updated.. now it add `^` before `<` and `>` symbols.

Comment: for before lessan than symbol only `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(message, "(?=<)", "^");`

Comment: ok. i believe it. but there is a difference between c# and vb? i got this output: "aaa^ccc". if i add the "@" before "@"(?=[><])", i got an error.

Comment: it works. my error was to write the output in a iframe and on it was only visibly in source. thanks for your help.